# "SyntaxError: invalid syntax" while installing Setuptools

Tags: python, pip, setuptools

I needed to install Setuptools for a project I was doing, and I had to download Setuptools through a .tar file (don't ask), but when ran the command I needed to use to install it:

```
C:\Users\myname\Downloads\setuptools-51.1.1>py -2 setup.py install
```

It ended up with a SyntaxError:

```py
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "setup.py", line 7, in <module>
        import setuptools
      File "C:\Users\myname\Downloads\setuptools-51.1.1\setuptools\__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
        import setuptools.version
      File "C:\Users\myname\Downloads\setuptools-51.1.1\setuptools\version.py", line 1, in <module>
        import pkg_resources
      File "C:\Users\myname\Downloads\setuptools-51.1.1\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 1365
        raise SyntaxError(e) from e
                                ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I'm using Python 2.7.

Why is it showing the error, and how can I fix it?

Edit:

When I looked into the `__init__.py` file, I found that there was something called an "invalid marker":

```py
    try:
        marker = packaging.markers.Marker(text)
        return marker.evaluate()
    except packaging.markers.InvalidMarker as e:
        raise SyntaxError(e) from e
```

Comment: That's python3 code. Why do you have to install from a .tar file and not through pip?

Comment: Don't use Python 2.7

Comment: @SuperStormer If I use pip, I have to use ```py -2 pip install setuptools``` because I installed python 3 before python 2. When I run that command, it throws this error: "C:\Python27\python.exe: can't open file 'pip': [Errno 2] No such file or directory"

Comment: `py -2 -m pip install setuptools`

Comment: @zabop The project I'm using setuptools for has python 2 syntax

Comment: I suggest then that you upgrade the project.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The last version of setuptools to support Python 2.7 was 44.1.1 (Jan 2020). See the [changelog](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/history.html#v45-0-0).

Upgrade your Python version in order to use setuptools 51.1.1.